# Informatica Cloud Data Integration - find non matching rows

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud, iics-di

I am working on Informatica Cloud Data
Integraion.I have 2 tables- Tab1 and Tab2.The joining column is id.I want to find all records in Tab1 that do not exist in Tab2.What transformations can I use to achieve this?

```
Tab1
id name
1  n1
2  n2
3  n3

Tab2
id
1
5
6
```

I want to get records with id 2 and 3 from tab1 as they do not exist in tab2

Answer (score 0):

You can use database source qualifier overwrite sql

```
Select * from table1 where id not in ( select id from table2)
```

Or else you can use informatica like below.

1. Do a lookup on table2, on join condition on id.
2. In exp transformation, create a flag
   `out_flag= iif(isnull (:lkp(id)),'pass','fail')`
3. Put a filter next and keep the condition as out_flag= 'pass'

Whole map should be like this

```
       Lkp
        |
Sq --exp|-----> fil---tgt
```